# vertical menu "floating over" horizontal navbar

Tags: html, css

In my recent project, i have add this menu to my index.html view:

```
      <table>
        <tr class="logo">
          <td><img src="#" alt="logo"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="menu">
          <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="menu">
          <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="menu">
          <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="menu">
          <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="menu">
          <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

this menu is placed inside this horizontal navbar:

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I want this menu floating over the navbar like that:

[image]

anyone know how to accomplish this?

my current css style for the table:

```
table {
  z-index: 1;
}

table > tr.logo {
  width: 280px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

table > tr.menu {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

table > tr.menu:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

table > tr.menu > a {
  text-decoration-color: #FAEBD7;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

table > tr.menu:hover > a {
  text-decoration-color: #FFFAF0;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/09br9e5p/

**UPDATE**

try update the code to avoid use tables, and i got this: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/09br9e5p/2/

Comment: I recommend against using tables for layouts, which includes menu layouts.

Would you be okay with some assistance that gave you semantic code to accomplish the same effects?

Also, is this menu to be a collapsible menu?

Comment: if I could make work with tables, i can try other layouts. i'm okay with any assistance to accomplish the effect i want. it's not a collapsible menu.

Comment: @MassDebates try update the code to avoid use tables ans i got this: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/09br9e5p/2/. How i made the items from the menu stay vertically placed and not horizontally?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I'm just confused about what you're doing or if it's something else. I'm going to rebuild a menu that looks like your diagram. Also, please verify the new answer and/or acknowledge its validity to your goal.

Do you want the image in the floating pop-out (but not collapsible) menu? It's 480 pixels tall by 280 pixels wide...

Comment: Nevermind. Your update totally confused me even more.

Sorry. If you can come up with a CLEAR diagram (It helps if you provide actual examples of what the menu choices could be like, (for example Appliances | Cars > Chevy, Ford, Honda | Furniture > Chairs, Beds, Tables | Computers ) as opposed to 'blablabla' and an actual image (could be a filler image) or something...) then I can help you.

Comment: @MassDebates I update again my jsfiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/09br9e5p/4/. now it's almost like what i wanted, but the navbar must be kept in its original height (the one if the menu is not present). the menu starts over the navbar and finishes in the left of the content.

Comment: @MassDebates I made another update 9https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/09br9e5p/5/) and now I finally getting close to the final result. now I just need fix the position of the navbar items (the first is being covered by the menu) and the background color of the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/09br9e5p/6/

I removed a lot of the unnecessary styles that were cluttering up the CSS. A key selector you were missing was:

```
header ul ul{
/* Stuff */
}
```

In the future, please be clear with what you're asking. This was terribly frustrating to understand you. I don't even fully know if this is close to what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have your image inside `<td></td>` instead make 1 more element and place it inside that.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono|Special+Elite|Luckiest+Guy|Slabo+27px|Open+Sans);

html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  width:100%;
}

header:after{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
}

header ul.right {
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 32px;
  float: right;
}

header li {
  float: left;
}

header li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Oxygen Mono';
}

header li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

header li.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

aside ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

aside li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
aside li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

aside li.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
}

.user {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

div.main {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

table {
  z-index: 1;
}

table > tr.logo {
  width: 280px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

table > tr.menu {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

table > tr.menu:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

table > tr.menu > a {
  text-decoration-color: #FAEBD7;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

table > tr.menu:hover > a {
  text-decoration-color: #FFFAF0;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header>
    <ul>
  <li><img class="logo" src="#" alt="logo"></li>
        <li>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              
            <tr class="menu">
              <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="menu">
              <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="menu">
              <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="menu">
              <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="menu">
              <td><a href="#">blablabla</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <main>
      <article>
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
```